# Pass multiple value as parameter to SQLDF

Tags: r

I have a data set as following:

```
Class Age
A     20
A     27 
B     30
C     31
```

I'm storing class in a variable i.e. `cl=c("A","B")`

And now want all records only for this class:

```
Out=sqldf(paste0("SELECT * from Data where Class in '","(","'",g,"'",")")
```

But I'm getting records only for the last class i.e. `B`.

How can I get records for all the `Class` which is there in the `cl` variable?

Comment: First  what is 'g' in your above code? It is not working because sqldf does not know how to work with vectors. Try `cl2 <- paste(cl, collapse=", ")` . Then put that in your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** See `?fn` (in gsubfn which is automatically pulled in by sqldf) and the sqldf github home page for the use of `fn$` to perform string interpolation.

```
library(sqldf)

cl <- c("A", "B")
fn$sqldf("SELECT * from Data where Class in (`toString(shQuote(cl))`) ")
```

**2)** or to look at the SQL generated first store it in a variable.

```
sql <- fn$c("SELECT * from Data where Class in (`toString(shQuote(cl))`) ")
sqldf(sql)
```

**3)** or put the portion to be substituted in a variable `CL` and then use fn's $ notation to refer to a variable:

```
CL <- toString(shQuote(cl))
sql <- fn$c("SELECT * from Data where Class in ($CL) ")
sqldf(sql)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Class Age 
A 20 
A 27 
B 30 
C 31"
Data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```